# Java file upload & rename with php

Tags: java, php, uploading, renaming

I'm trying to upload & rename a file from a java program.

My java upload method:

```
public void bestandUploaden(String oudeUrl, String nieuweNaam) throws ParseException, IOException {
System.out.println("oude url: " + oudeUrl);
System.out.println("nieuwe naam: " + nieuweNaam); 
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("**Website url**/upload_file.php");
File file = new File(oudeUrl);

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
mpEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
mpEntity.addPart("uniekeNaam", new StringBody(nieuweNaam));

httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
  resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

My php code:

```
<?php
echo "Nieuwe bestandsnaam :" . $_FILES["uniekeNaam"];
$disallowedExts = array("exe");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if (!in_array($extension, $disallowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("documenten/" . $_FILES["uniekeNaam"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["uniekeNaam"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "documenten/" . $_FILES["uniekeNaam"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "documenten/" . $_FILES["uniekeNaam"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

My java console output:

```
oude url: D:\Dropbox\Documents\youtube.txt
nieuwe naam: Een_textbestand.txt
executing request POST **Website url**/upload_file.php HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Nieuwe bestandsnaam :Upload: youtube.txt<br>Type: application/octet-stream<br>Size: 1.8095703125 kB<br>Temp file: /tmp/phpp9igba<br> already exists.
```

As you can see the 'uniekeNaam' isn't transfered from my java to my php part.
It's empty. I don't have any php knowledge and tried different things but nothing seems to work. I just want to be able to browse to a file in my java program and upload that file to a webserver and rename it.
If I leave the renaming out it works so I think I just need to figure out how to transfer the 'uniekeNaam' from java to php.

If i do:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

I get:

```
Array ( 
   [file] => Array ( 
      [name] => motoplus.pdf 
      [type] => application/octet-stream 
      [tmp_name] => /tmp/php0V4SCS 
      [error] => 0 [size] => 1010671 
   ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php file just type:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

to see whether you are receiving that "uniekeNaam" variable or not.

Comment: Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => motoplus.pdf
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php0V4SCS
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1010671
        )

) Not receiving it

Comment: Following answer has the solution you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965022/android-upload-file-with-filling-out-post-body-together